# Running ggplot in script, saved variable and called print(). Plot window STILL not showing.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following in my script:

```
X <- as.numeric(colnames(sers$spectra))
Y <- sers$spectra[1, ]

require(ggplot2)
emptydf <- data.frame()
p <- ggplot(emptydf, aes(x=X, y=Y))
p <- p + geom_line()
print(p)

message("Press Return To Continue")
invisible(readLines("stdin", n=1))
```

When I execute this, I see:

```
$ Rscript analyze.R
Loading required package: pls

Attaching package: ‘pls’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    loadings

Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: methods
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type AsIs. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type AsIs. Defaulting to continuous
Press Return To Continue
```

I've tried using this in my console and it works. I've persisted the output of ggplot() into a variable and tried to print it here.

I need the last two lines otherwise my script will terminate. When I execute this, I don't see any plot window. Why?

Comment: Windows don't generally open up when you run R non-interactively. If you "print" a plot, it goes to the default graphics device which is the PDF writer when you run from Rscript. You could explicitly open a graphics window but determining the right one is dependent on your OS.

Comment: It seems from your new question you have solved this. Maybe you should post your solution as an answer or at least link to wherever you found it.